# Magento attribute default order on config products

Tags: magento, attributes

Anyone knows how Magento sorts attributes order in config products frontend?

I.e.: I have two attribute "size" and "color" applied to 2000 configurable products.
On frontend it show first size then color: I want to change this default order without updating all products..

Already tried changing attribute name and attribute order field in db: nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You need to given sort order to product attribute

Please refer snapshot
[image]

Comment: The only way I could manage to work is to change the attribute id: in fact seems that Magento default attributes order is by attribute ID.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could manage to work is to change the attribute id: in fact seems that Magento default attributes order is by attribute ID.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a solution (You can do this in magento admin)

Go to the configurable product, go to the tab where u connect it to simpel products.

In the box labeled "Super product attributes configuration" you can drag and drop the position of the attribute (if you have more than 1)